# Is it okay to remove oil/grease stains from anodized aluminum pan using vinegar?

Tags: oil, cleaning, aluminum-cookware

I bought a brand new hard anodized pan for making roti. I used some oil while cooking. After cooking, washing I saw these stains (most likely grease) that would not be removed after washing with my usual dish washing liquid.

[Pan photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcsFn.jpg)

I heated the pan hoping that oil would come off. It didn't.

Then I gently scrubbed vinegar soaked toothbrush on the greasy spot. Some of the grease got removed, (50%) but it remained there in other spots.

Is my cleaning process correct?

Answer (score -1):

Try this approach, as [I describe on my blog](http://www.smartfoodguide.com/an-aluminium-cookware-ready-reckoner-guide/):

> 1) Fill the pot or pan or other aluminium utensil with water.
>
> 2) Add a tablespoon of vinegar or two teaspoons of cream of tartar for every quart of water.
>
> 3) Boil this solution for 10 to 15 minutes and scour the vessel with a soapy steel wool pad.
>
> 4) Rinse and dry.

Comment: A major point is that winegar is less effective than water alone, as far as the material to be removed is fat or grease.. If really necessary I would go with a non greasy clear and crispy solvent. Such as acetone or nail enamel remover  It could be unpleasant in a kitchen but assuming a thorough washing / evaporation, no health concerns. Obviously I am a chemist :)